# Java - How to add a JLabel that contains an image to a pdf file in iText

Tags: java, mysql, swing, pdf, itext

I want to add an image which is retrieved from the mysql db and print it on a pdf file in iText java. The image retrieved from the db is stored in the lblimg. How do I achieve that in java ? 
Here's my partial code:

```
String filename = null;
int s = 0;
byte[] person_img = null;

uploadbtn = new JButton("Upload a Photo");
uploadbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();

        try{
            File img = new File(filename);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(img);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            for(int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;){
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
            }

            person_img = bos.toByteArray();


            fis.close();

        }catch(Exception e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

// Partial code for adding image to db
stt.setBytes(8, person_img);

 // Partial codes for retrieving image from db
byte[] imageData = rs.getBytes("Image");
format = new ImageIcon(imageData);
 lblimg.setIcon(format);

  //Creating the document and adding the lblimg (which contains the image retrieved from the db). PLEASE HELP HERE. I CANNOT ADD THE IMAGE TO PDF document.
  Document doc = new Document();
 PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Report.pdf"));
doc.open();

doc.add(new Paragraph( // img to be added here ));
```

**Update 1 by Bruno Lowagie**

Snippet taken from the full code:

```
try {
    Image i = Image.getInstance((PdfTemplate) lblimg.getIcon());
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Report.pdf"));
    doc.open();
    Image img = Image.getInstance("ja.png");
    doc.add(img);
    doc.add(i);
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Employee Information", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED)));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("______________________________________________________________________________"));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Employee ID is " + val1));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("First Name is " + val2 + "\t\t" + " Last Name is " + val3));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Job Position " + val4));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Allowances allowed " + val5));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Salary " + val10));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Report Saved");
    doc.close();
} catch(Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

As `getIcon` returns a `javax.swing` class and as `PdfTemplate` is an iText class extending the `PdfContentByte` class that contains a `ByteBuffer` of PDF syntax, a `ClassCastException` is thrown here: `(PdfTemplate) lblimg.getIcon()`

**Update 2 by Bruno Lowagie**

The actual question was posted as a comment: How do I retrieve an image which is in a JLabel and add it on a PDF? This question is answered in update 3 of my answer.

Comment: I still see `Image i = Image.getInstance((PdfTemplate) lblimg.getIcon());` in that code, proving my point that you don't listen to good advice. In my answer I clearly said that `Image i = Image.getInstance((PdfTemplate) lblimg.getIcon());` is *completely* wrong. **You can not cast a javax.swing.Icon to a com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate!**

Comment: Please clarify this for me.. I'm blank

Comment: I've updated your question *and* I've updated my answer. It goes beyond comprehension why you'd cast a *javax.swing* `Icon` to a *com.itextpdf.text.pdf* `PdfTemplate`. You say you've done a lot of effort, but doing a lot of effort is wrong when you don't know what you're doing. You can save yourself a lot of effort by studying and doing the right thing. Asking other people to teach you on StackOverflow is not a good alternative for studying.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie The error still persists http://pastebin.com/x7QS5Gne

There are not other ways to do this ?

Comment: When you say *The error still persists*, you also have to say *which error* you get. Is it a `ClassCastException`? Or is it something else. You are constantly asking half questions. You shouldn't be surprised when you only get half answers. People run out of patience and then you are on your own. Too bad.

Comment: The error is java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Comment: **LOL** You're not even talking about a PDF or an iText problem. You're having an SQL problem. Thank you for wasting my time!

Comment: This error occurs when I create the pdf.. I guess the issue is the rs.getBytes{"Image"); 

The error is pointing to that..

Comment: You are a troll, aren't you? Where did I say that you could use `byte[] imageData = rs.getBytes("Image");` in your action??? What makes you think you can still use `rs`??? You already have an `Icon` instance. Why don't you use that?

Comment: Can you cast `lblimg.getIcon()` to an `ImageIcon`? What happens if you do that?

Comment: How to use the Icon instance ? 
Please help I am confused :(

Comment: Did you read the update in my answer. (I have a strong feeling that you don't read any of my advice.)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I would like to express my sincere gratitude to you man ! 
You are a life saver :) Despite several discussions, the code now works :) 
Apologies for troubling you this much.. I guess the too many updates, lol that's couldnt figure out much and was confused. These discussions are worth ! (Y) 

Glad to know that you are the creator of iText :)

Comment: I can be grumpy, but I can't resist a puzzle. It beats making Sudoku's.

Comment: You have patience ! :D
Thanks for bearing with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this contains an image:

```
byte[] imageData = rs.getBytes("Image");
```

In other words: assuming that `imageData` is a valid JPEG, JPEG2000, GIF, PNG, BMP, WMF, TIFF or JBIG2 image, then you can create a `com.itextpdf.text.Image` object like this:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(imageData);
```

Once you have this `img` instance, you can add it to the document like this:

```
document.add(img);
```

I don't understand why you'd create an `ImageIcon` instance. Nor is it clear why you refer to a `Paragraph` object.

**Update 1:**

Now that I see your full code, I see a very strange line:

```
Image i = Image.getInstance((PdfTemplate) lblimg.getIcon());
```

You are casting a `javax.swing` object to an iText object. This can never work. You should get a `ClassCastException` at this point in your code.

I also see that you know how to add an image from a file:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance("ja.png");
doc.add(img);
```

When you don't have a path to a file, the fastest way you'll find alternative `getInstance()` methods, is by consulting the Javadoc API documentation: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#getInstance(byte[])

**Update 2:**

I have updated the question so that it contains the relevant code. As explained in my answer (that unfortunately wasn't accepted), the following line throws a `ClassCastException`:

```
Image i = Image.getInstance((PdfTemplate) lblimg.getIcon());
```

This exception is caught like this:

```
} catch(Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hence all the code starting with the following line is skipped:

```
Document doc = new Document();
```

As a result, no document is created. This is not an iText problem. This is a case of bad exception handling.

**Update 3:**

Finally, the real question is asked in a comment: *In simple words: How to I retrieve an image which is in a JLabel and add it on a PDF?*

Again it turns out that I have already answered that question. I referred to the Javadoc API documentation for the [Image](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html) class. We find the following `getInstance()` method: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#getInstance(java.awt.Image, java.awt.Color)

In other words, we can create an iText `Image` object using a Java `Image` object. You have the following line in your code:

```
ImageIcon format = new ImageIcon(imageData);
```

Or, in your case, you could try something like:

```
ImageIcon format = (ImageIcon)lblimg.getIcon();
```

You can get a `java.awt.Image` object from this `ImageIcon` [like this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage()):

```
java.awt.Image awtImage = format.getImage();
```

As per the iText API documentation, you can create an iText image like this:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(awtImage, null);
```

Comment: Nope. does not work man.. 
See my form http://i.imgbox.com/kyGJ64qJ.png

I want the picture to be displayed on the pdf when I click the print button.
The full codes are in the above comment section

Comment: That's a *totally different* question. First you complain that you can't add an image retrieved from a database as a `byte[]` to a PDF (because you cast a `javax.swing` object to an iText object), now you are asking us to debug your broken action handling in a Swing component.

Comment: my action handling is fine. My complain remains the same though. 
I'm just telling you the process that I am using to add the image retrieved from the db to the PDF.

Comment: Then I agree with @AndrewThompson in the sense that your question is so unclear that it is impossible for anyone to answer it. I hope you understand. I honestly have no clue about what you're asking.

Comment: In simple words.. How to I retrieve an image which is in a JLabel and add it on a PDF ?